# PHP works, then stops

Tags: php, forms

I created a basic form.  This code doesn't work.  I don't see anything in the code that would cause this.

There's a GET in the access log but no POST.   There's no entry in the error log.

```
<?php

$clientName = "";
$squareFeet = 0;
$capRate    = 0;
$utilityBillSavings = 0;
$cashPayments = 0;
$prodVal = 0;

  if(isset($_POST["clientName"]) && isset($_POST['squareFeet']) && isset($_POST['capRate']) && isset($_POST['utilityBillSavings']) && isset($_POST['cashPayments'])) {
    $clientName           = $_POST['clientName']; echo $clientName . "<br>";
    $squareFeet           = $_POST['squareFeet']; echo $squareFeet . "<br>";
    $capRate              = $_POST['capRate']; echo $capRate . "<br>";
    $utilityBillSavings   = $_POST['utilityBillSavings']; echo $utilityBillSavings . "<br>";
    $cashPayments         = $_POST['cashPayments']; echo $cashPayments . "<br>";
    $capRate              = $capRate / 100;
    $propVal              = (($utilityBillSavings/$squareFeet)/$capRate)*$squareFeet;
    echo "Property Value Increase is: " . $propVal . "<br>";
  }

?>
<html><head><body>
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" name="form" id="form">
    <div>Client name</div><div><input type="text" name="clientName" size="20"></div>
    <div>Sq Ft</div><div><input type="number" name="squareFeet" min="0" max="1000000000000"></div>
    <div>Cap Rate</div><div><input type="number" name="capRate"  min="0" max="1000000000000"></div>
    <div>Bill Savings</div><div><input type="number" name="utilityBillSavings"  min="0" max="1000000000000"></div>
    <div>Cash Payment</div><div><input type="number" name="cashPayments"  min="0" max="1000000000000"></div>
    <div><input type="button" name="submit" value="   Calculate Increase In Property Value   "></div>
  </form>

</body></html>
```

Comment: What do you mean it stops working? Is error reporting enabled?

Comment: Check your server error logs to find out if it's throwing any error messages. I'd probably suggest making sure the `$_POST` values exist with isset/!empty/array_key_exists when you assign them to new variables, as it could throw an `undefined index` error.

Comment: Already checked the logs.  No errors.  Entry is a POST with a response code of 200 OK.

Comment: I mean it stopped working meaning it doesn't recognize the POST.  I added the ELSE to the IF statement and two echo statements, one before the IF and one after the IF and as the ELSE so I could tell where I was when I click the Submit button.

I get the echo response in ELSE statement.

It should be working from what I can see.

Comment: Please find two versions, one of which works, and one of which does not, and post both of them. You should be able to do that quite easily if, as you say, it stops working  when you add more fields.

Comment: Any reason this code wouldn't work?